# Seaside - Page formatting

Tags: html, css, smalltalk, seaside

Our page renders to something along the lines of:
[image]

Is there a way to maybe format this a little better? For example, maybe have the labels in one column and the inputs in another?

Here is a snippet of our code:

```
renderContentOn: html

    html horizontalRule.
    html horizontalRule.
    html heading level: 2; with: 'System Warnings & Errors:'.
    html horizontalRule.
    (SpendingManager warningsFound = false) ifFalse: [ 
        self renderWarnings.
        WarningsReport renderContentOn: html.
        SpendingManager clearProblemList.

    html horizontalRule.
    html horizontalRule.
    ].

        html heading level: 2; with: 'Create A Fund:'.
            html form: [
            html label: 'Code:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #fName of: FundCreator.
                html break.
            html label: '   Starting Amount:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #amount of: FundCreator.
                html break.

        html submitButton
            callback: [(FundCreator fName = '') ifFalse: [FundCreator createFromUI.] 
                                                ifTrue: [SpendingManager addProblem: 'SP0002']. 
            self renderReport ];
            text: 'Create Fund'.
        ].

        html heading level: 2; with: 'Create A GLAC:'.
        html form: [

            html label: 'Code:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #gName of: GLACCreator.
                html break.

            html label: '   Debit Fund:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #dFund of: GLACCreator.
                html break.

            html label: '   Credit Fund:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #cFund of: GLACCreator.
                html break.

            html label: '   Description:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #descr of: GLACCreator.
                html break.

        html submitButton
            callback: [GLACCreator createFromUI. self renderReport ];
            text: 'Create GLAC'.

    ].

        html heading level: 2; with: 'Create a Transaction:'.
        html form: [

            html label: 'GLAC:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #aGLAC of: TransactionCreator.
                html break.

            html label: '   Amount:  '.
            html textInput
            on: #amount of: TransactionCreator.
                html break.

        html submitButton
            callback: [TransactionCreator createFromUI. self renderReport ];
            text: 'Create Transaction'.

    ].
```

Comment: Just a discussion: who invented `seaside` ? it sounds more complicated than writing HTML.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor [Avi Bryant](http://about.me/avibryant) among others. It depends on what you define complicated. It is a little more verbose, but normally you split things into multiple components.

Comment: Apart from styling (which you probably want to do with CSS), you should consider breaking up your code into multiple components.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor When building complex applications, it is a lot less verbose than using either html or a template language.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do.

The easier one would be to render a table and put all labels into one column and the text inputs into the other one. You'd use css to make the table and cell borders invisible.

The better solution is to assign a css class to labels and again use css to make all labels the same size and orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do this in CSS, that's what it's for. You can set labels and input elements to display as a block, and then use width and alignment to get the layout you want.

Something like this should get you started:

```
form label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.3em;

  width: 15em;
}

form input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
}

form br {
  clear: left;
}
```